# Drain oscillations on PFS7329H

Tags: power-supply, oscillation, power-factor-correction

I have 100V/200W PSU with PFC and I see attached waveform on drain of PFS7329H controller. How can I get rid of it? PSU seems to work fine, but I see EMI issues.

[image: Oscillations on Drain]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this: -

[image]

It's pretty normal stuff for a power factor correction boost circuit as per the [PFS7329H](https://www.mouser.co.uk/datasheet/2/328/hiperpfs-2_family_datasheet-911128.pdf).

> *but I see EMI issues*

Well, you haven't said what they are but the normal concern is fast rising or falling edges because they possess the highest value of dv/dt or di/dt and will capacitively or magnetically couple more readily than a much slower looking sinewave. So, EMI when the MOSFET activates and deactivates is probably the first place to look.

Comment: I see conducted interferences on 6 MHz and 15 MHz. They vary with load. I'm using home made LISN to measure interferences.

Comment: Well, the decaying sinewave looks like 210 kHz to me so you decide if it's that or the more powerful energy transfer from inductor via MOSFET to bulk storage capacitor.

Comment: I thought that my PFC don't work correctly. I don't think this oscillations is direct EMI problem.

Comment: I don't either - are we finished here?

Answer (score 1):

At 5uS/division, these cycles are 2.5uS or 500,000 Hertz. So the EMI is from another source.

Comment: I know. I thought maybe my PFC is not working well and this is an indirect problem.